# How do you align a title to the left-most object within a Grid with justify="space-between" in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Grid container containing four Grid items. The first Grid item is full width and contains a title. The other three Grid items contain avatars. I want to align the avatars to the right of the page and I would like the title to align with the left-most avatar. However, it is currently further to the left than the avatars. The other issue is that the number of avatars can vary (likely between 1 and 3 but possibly more). How can I ensure the left-most avatar and title align?

Here is the result I am getting:

[image]

And here is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, makeStyles, Typography, Divider, Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  header: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(3),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

const Header = ({ padding }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        container
        item
        direction="row"
        justify="space-between"
        align-items="center"
        xs={12}
        className={`${padding} ${classes.header}`}
      >
        {/*Page title and description*/}
        <Grid item xs>
          <Typography variant="h1" component="h1">
            Page Title
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1">
            This is a description of what the page is about
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        {/*People container*/}
        <Grid item xs className={classes.smeSection} alignItems="bottom">
          {/*People profiles*/}

          <Grid container item justify="flex-end" alignItems="bottom">
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography variant="h5">People</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Avatar/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Avatar/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Avatar />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Divider />
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Many thanks!

Katie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By continuously nesting flexbox components it is very easy to make mistakes and get lost in the code.

If it was that I understood your requirement well, here is the code with which I managed to get that layout:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Typography, Divider, Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container direction="row" align-items="center">
        {/*Page title and description*/}
        <Grid item xs={9}>
          <Typography variant="h1" component="h1">
            Page Title
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1">
            This is a description of what the page is about
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        {/*People container*/}
        <Grid container item xs={3}>
          {/*People profiles*/}
          <Grid container item>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography variant="h5">People</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item>
                <Avatar />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Avatar />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Avatar />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Divider />
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

A grid can be "container", "item" or both. The most important changes I made to your code was to make all grid parents "containers" and add a width size to the first two grid items (xs={9} and xs={3}).

Here's a CodeSandbox with a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-banzai-0gp10?file=/src/Header.js:0-1119

In my opinion, I think a better alternative is to use a combination of Grid (for general layout) and Flexbox to align the nested elements.

**UPDATE:**
With the new data you added as a reference I made the layout again using flexbox.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Typography,
  makeStyles,
  Avatar,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  Divider
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  usersHeader: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  personCards: {
    display: "flex"
  }
}));

const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div>
          <Typography variant="h3" component="h1">
            Page Title
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1">
            This is a description of what the page is about
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Typography className={classes.usersHeader} variant="subtitle">
            Users
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.personCards}>
            <Card elevation={0}>
              <CardHeader
                avatar={<Avatar />}
                title="Person name"
                subheader="Person role"
              />
            </Card>
            <Card elevation={0}>
              <CardHeader
                avatar={<Avatar />}
                title="Person name"
                subheader="Person role"
              />
            </Card>
            <Card elevation={0}>
              <CardHeader
                avatar={<Avatar />}
                title="Person name"
                subheader="Person role"
              />
            </Card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Divider />
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

[image]

CodeSandbox reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-cartwright-grxhj?file=/src/Header.js

Comment: Hi Kelvin. Many thanks for your reply. I have realised I left out a crucial part of the description - the number of avatars may vary between 1 and 3, and so I want the avatars to line up with the right but the title above to line up with the left. If the grid size is fixed at xs={9} then it means that if there is only one avatar it will be too far in the center of the page. I like your idea of using a flexbox. I'll investigate this. I'll also update the above post with an image to help explain the issue! Thanks again for kindly responding to my question.

Comment: Hi Katie, I updated my answer using a flexbox approach, I hope it helps.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect!  Thanks again Kelvin for coming back and helping. I am new to React and haven't done web development for a few years, so your answer has really helped my learning as well. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Oh, by the way - I notice that you have used divs in your code. My colleague keeps reviewing my code and asking me to change divs to Box because "we're using material ui, so should go all-in". But I often see examples online (including on the Material UI website) that use divs instead of Box, so I wondered whether there was any reason why I should be using Box when div seems to do the job well! Thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome, divs are often used for performance reasons, I also thought that the box component was the natural substitute for divs, but I read in some issues that the implementation of dynamic styles creates a significant performance difference. Some issues: 
1) https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21657
2) https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21797

Comment: Thanks Kelvin - this is very useful info and makes total sense. Much appreciated :)